# Visual Studio 2019 Community offline activation

Tags: visual-studio-2019, community

I'm trying to keep Visual Studio 2019 Community lincensed without internet access for more than 30 days. I need this, because I'm creating a master image for a lab environment with multiple computers, which has no internet access.

With Visual Studio 2017 Community I was able to activate it once using a valid MS account, and that information was kept in the master image, so it worked offline for more than 30 days on every computer, for every user.

This isn't working with Visual Studio 2019 Community anymore. It handles licenses more dynamically (per computer and per user i guess). So I would need to activate Visual Studio 2019 Community everytime a new user logs in on any of the lab computers. Even if i could do that (which is ridiculous), I'm not able to do that without an internet connection.

Is there a way to activate Visual Studio 2019 Community offline?

Comment: Your use case is not supported. See [Extend a trial version or update a license](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-unlock-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) which states `(Visual Studio Community is free without a trial period. However, you must sign in periodically to keep your license up to date.)`. For offline activation it seems like you'd need a serial.

Comment: Only Professional and Enterprise editions accept serials, so I would need to buy one of those editions for offline use.
However, I found an unsupported method in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43390466/is-visual-studio-community-a-30-day-trial